# Adhoc provisionning profile and development push notification SSL

Tags: ios, push-notification, ssl-certificate, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

I have a very specific question. please, read it carefully before you sign the question as possible duplicate.

> Should push notification work when using development push notification service SSL certificate with an app. signed with an adhoc
>   provisioning profile?

I want to send the app. for testers. therefore, I signed it with an adhoc provisioning profile. should I create the SSL certificate for production now and use in the server in-able to send notifications for the testers app?

Comment: :) you are the one who answer it. I believe it was the perfect time to ask the question. since you are online.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, an app signed with AdHoc provisioning profile works only with the production push environment and production push certificate.

Comment: While this was absolutely correct at the time, anybody reading now should note that you can now create a push certificate that works with both environments - or even use the new Token Based Authentication.